# Word for something that cannot be traversed because it is too deep

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective describing something that cannot be traversed because it is too deep.

> We could not cross the river. The river was _______

The only word I can think of that comes close is "insurmountable", but this word usually describes something that  cannot be crossed because it is too *tall*, and doesn't seem to fit for a deep river (or deep valley or deep hole, etc).

Comment: '**something**' ??  You're looking for an all-purpose word that ignores the specific nature of the thing being traversed? Or do you mean **river**?

Comment: @TimRomano I'm looking for a word specifying that the property of the thing that prevents it being traversed is its depth. I have clarified the question accordingly

Comment: But what does the depth have to do with it, when a river is concerned?  Boats can cross the deepest water.  People swim in old quarries that are hundreds of feet deep. Are you thinking of being unable to **ford** the river?

Comment: @TimRomano Depth is sometimes an issue if, for example, you don't have a boat and are unwilling to swim. I am looking for a word that would equally be applicable to a valley, deep and wide hole, canyon, or anything where its sheer depth poses the majority of the issue in crossing it.

Comment: If you don't have a boat and are unwilling to swim, then the river only has to be deeper than your nose is tall. Not very deep. Maybe you want to get rid of the river example and stick to canyons and chasms and crevasses.

Comment: Seems to me that it's over your head/

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just state "because it was too deep"!

Comment: *too deep*,... *fathomless*

Comment: The river was too **wide**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The river was [**unfordable**](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=559&bih=368&noj=1&ei=d7kWV4m0EcSxa5Cgl-AP&q=%22deep+unfordable+river%22&oq=%22deep+unfordable+river%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...8816.16062.0.16846.18.15.0.0.0.0.534.2713.0j3j5j0j1j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..10.1.209.AWd_LxrJckI)*

> [unfordable](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/fordable)
>
> :  incapable of being forded :  impassable *an unfordable river*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfordable)
>
> *We could not cross the river. The river was **unfordable**.*

Comment: Given that to ford means "to cross at a shallow place", I think this fits best. It feels odd to use it with anything but a river, though.

Comment: While I think that is a great answer, a river can be unfordable also because of a current that is too swift/strong or other reasons besides simple depth.

Answer (score 3):

Impassable sounds right to me.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impassable?s=t

The first definition fits :

> not passable; not allowing passage over, through, along, etc.:

Answer (score 1):

Impassable describes the fact you can't get across it, though it doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 1):

**[Unfathomable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfathomable)** can be used in this context

**Unfathomable**:

> ```
> Difficult or impossible to measure: the unfathomable depths
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to say something like

They had to turn back at the canyon because it seemed **bottomless**.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the noun [“depth”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depth) in a single sentence:

“We could not ford the river/[cross the valley] because of its depth."

> depth
>   1 a (1) :  a deep place in a body of water ‘fish living at
>   great depths’ (2) :  a part that is far from the outside or surface
>   ‘the depths of the woods’ (3) :  abyss
>    …
>   2 a :  the perpendicular
>   measurement downward from a surface
>       …
>   3 :  the quality of being
>   deep

(Merriam-Webster)

In your context and two-sentence example, you could also consider modifying the river’s/valley’s depth instead of the river/valley itself:

“We could not cross the river/valley.  Its depth was too great."